# ASP.NET Web API - Configure the JSON response to conform to JSON API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ember.js

Version 1 of my ASP.NET Web API for Ember.js was producing JSON that looked like this:

```
     [{"id":1,"name":"House of Crap","category":"Retail","street_name":"Washington Street"},
     {"id":2,"name":"Sketchy Automotive","category":"Automotive","street_name":"4th Street"},
     {"id":3,"name":"Toxins Are Us","category":"Chemical","street_name":"Highway 93"},
     {"id":4,"name":"Tricky Restaurant","category":"Restaurant","street_name":"4th Street"}]
```

I need something that looks like this:

```
     {"property":
     [{"id":1,"name":"House of Crap","category":"Retail","street_name":"Washington Street"},
     {"id":2,"name":"Sketchy Automotive","category":"Automotive","street_name":"4th Street"},
     {"id":3,"name":"Toxins Are Us","category":"Chemical","street_name":"Highway 93"},
     {"id":4,"name":"Tricky Restaurant","category":"Restaurant","street_name":"4th Street"}]}
```

One of my subs accomplished this as follows: He created a simple view-model class.

```
    namespace EnvironWeb.ViewModels
    {
        public class PropertyVM
        {
            public IEnumerable<property> property { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

He then made the GetProperties controller method of the type of the new class.

```
    public PropertyVM GetProperties()
    {
        var model = new PropertyVM();
        model.property = repository.GetAll();

        return model;
    }
```

It's clever, but is it the best approach? The JsonConverter looks promising, but I'm not sure I can accomplish it with the JsonConverter.

Answer (score 1):

This is not `the best` approach, this is `the correct` approach :)

Bur I would suggest to review your model. Why do you need root property in the answer? Does it have any business meaning? If only reason for this root property is some simplification of code on client side - may be it's better to keep API clean and just do the work on client side?

Comment: Thanks dmay, I'm trying to conform to the JSON API, but perhaps you're right. I'll consider doing the work on the client side.